# sql query with sum or column

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g

I have a table color_balls entries as below

```
=====================================================
Name    Red_Ball    Green_Ball  Yellow_Ball     
=====================================================
John       27           56          66
Mathew     37           45          15
=====================================================
```

I want to write a sql or mysql query to get the output as below.

```
=====================================
Color_of_Balls      No_of_balls
=====================================
Red_Ball            64
Green_Ball          101
Yellow_Ball         81
=====================================
```

Comment: Are you using mysql or oracle10g (both are tagged)?

Comment: It would be helpful if I get the queries in both sql and oracle10g.Will the query work in both sql anl and oracle10g?

Comment: The below query will work for both.  Oracle has a unique solution which will not work for MySQL - see below.

Answer (score 4):

This type of query is called UNPIVOT, which unfortunately isn't natively supported by MySQL.  However, you can simulate this using UNION:

```
SELECT 'Red_Ball' AS Color_of_Balls, SUM(Red_Ball) as No_of_Balls
FROM color_balls
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Green_Ball', SUM(Green_Ball)
FROM color_balls
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Yellow_Ball', SUM(Yellow_Ball)
FROM color_balls
```

Oracle10g doesn't support this natively either, although there is [this workaround](http://www.bobjankovsky.org/show.php?seq=97).

Comment: `union all` is much preferable to `union`, when you know there are no duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Noted and updated.  Probably wouldn't matter much here though :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work in both Oracle and MySQL:

```
SELECT b.Color_of_Balls
     , CASE b.Color_of_Balls 
         WHEN 'Red_Ball'    THEN d.sum_red_ball
         WHEN 'Green_Ball'  THEN d.sum_green_ball
         WHEN 'Yellow_Ball' THEN d.sum_yellow_ball
       END AS No_of_balls
  FROM ( SELECT 'Red_Ball' AS Color_of_Balls FROM DUAL 
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Green_Ball' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Yellow_Ball' FROM DUAL
       ) b
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(c.Red_Ball)    AS sum_red_ball
              , SUM(c.Green_Ball)  AS sum_green_ball
              , SUM(c.Yellow_Ball) AS sum_yellow_ball
           FROM color_balls c
       ) d
 ORDER
    BY CASE b.Color_of_Balls 
         WHEN 'Red_Ball'    THEN 1
         WHEN 'Green_Ball'  THEN 2
         WHEN 'Yellow_Ball' THEN 3
       END
```

Note that this approach requires only one pass through the `color_balls` table, rather than three separate passes through the table (or more, depending on how many rows you need returned.)

Comment: LEFT JOIN requires a joining condition. But perhaps you meant CROSS JOIN (which doesn't expect a condition)?

Comment: Good catch, Andriy. A LEFT JOIN would work as well, if I included a dummy ON clause that evaluates to true (in both MySQL and Oracle) e.g.  `ON 1=1`.